# pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError FastAPI application

Tags: python, fastapi

I am developing a simple FastAPI application, that will retrieve data from our SQL database based on a specific user number, then print out the data attributed to that user on our application. However, I find I am getting a ValidationError but it won't print the output to the console.

The below is the script to retrieve with asyncio data from oracle sql.

```
# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Templates configuration
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class SQLFast:
    """TQL allows you to perform any type of SQL command in Python"""
    async def __aenter__(self):
        # Using cx_Oracle_async.create_pool to create an asynchronous connection pool
        self.pool = await cx_Oracle_async.create_pool(
            user=DB_USERNAME,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
            dsn=f"{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_SERVICE}",
            # maxconn=4,
        )
        self.connection = await self.pool.acquire()
        # Creating an asynchronous cursor
        self.cursor = await self.connection.cursor()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        #await self.cursor.close()
        await self.pool.release(self.connection)
    async def sql_query(self, query: str, return_type=pd.DataFrame, big_query=False):
        """Returns either a DataFrame or a list from a query"""
        try:
            await self.cursor.execute(query)
    
            if return_type == pd.DataFrame:
                result = await self.cursor.fetchall()
                if result:
                    # Fetch columns directly from the result set
                    columns = getattr(result, "columns", None)
                    if columns is not None:
                        return pd.DataFrame(result, columns=columns)
                    else:
                        return pd.DataFrame(result)
                else:
                    return pd.DataFrame()  # Return an empty DataFrame for no result
            elif return_type == list:
                return await self.cursor.fetchall()
    
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error executing SQL query: {e}")
            raise
```

Dependencies and root-path:

```
app = FastAPI()

# Dependency to get the SQLFast instance
async def get_tql_fast():
    async with SQLFast() as tql:
        yield tql

# Dependency to get the Jinja2 template renderer
def get_templates():
    return templates

# Dependency to get the current request
def get_request(request):
    return request

# Default route for the root path ("/")
@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return JSONResponse(content={"message": "Welcome to the API!"})
```

API to read data from SQL and import to web application:

```
# API route to get data from the Oracle database using SQLFast
@app.get("/api/data/{user_no}", response_model=dict)
async def read_data(user_no: int, tql: SQLFast = Depends(get_tql_fast)):
    query = f"SELECT * FROM chef_product WHERE user_no = {user_no}"
    try:
        result = await tql.sql_query(query, return_type=pd.DataFrame)

        if result is not None:
            # Fetch columns directly from the result set
            columns = list(result.columns)
            return result.to_dict(orient="records")
        else:
            return []

    except ValidationError as e:
        logger.error(f"Validation error in API route /api/data: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail=str(e))

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in API route /api/data: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")


# Web route to display data on a webpage
@app.get("/web/data/{user_no}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def read_web_data(user_no: int, tql: SQLFast = Depends(get_tql_fast), templates=Depends(get_templates)):
    query = f"SELECT * FROM chef_product WHERE user_no = {user_no}"
    try:
        data = await tql.sql_query(query)
        data_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[desc[0] for desc in tql.cursor.description])
        return templates.TemplateResponse("web_data.html", {"request": get_request(), "data": data_df})

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in web route /web/data: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Internal Server Error")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

I run with the curl command:

```
    except ValidationError as e:
        logger.error(f"Validation error in API route /api/data: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=422, detail=str(e))
```

This produces the following error output:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [16300] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [5396]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:61063 - "GET /api/data/120981833 HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 407, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 270, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 124, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 75, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 64, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 680, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 275, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 249, in app
    content = await serialize_response(
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 138, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: <unprintable ValidationError object>
```